# Sending the same continuous updates to multiple threads spawned by another thread

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm struggling to get my head around this so hoping for a bit of input.

I plan on having a thread running a socket server, that checks every second for new client connections. If it finds one, it will spawn a thread for that connection, and close it once the client is disconnected. This is the bit I have working.

I would like to get information from the main program passed to the end threads, so that every client receives the same information. I can't really use `multiprocessing.Queue` as that would delete the item after the first thread used it (and I can't intercept it in the server thread as the updates would be limited to 1 per second, and the main thread won't know how many connections there are), so does anyone have any suggestions?

The layout of threads is a bit like this:

```
Main script (running many times per second)
    -server (running 1 time per second)
        -client (sending information as soon as it receives it, ideally in sync with the main script)
        -client
        -client
```

I guess I could probably spawn a thread from the server to receive input, and that thread will then spawn the client threads and send a different `Queue` item to each one, but it sounds like there should be a less messy way.

Edit: The inbetween thread idea doesn't work, you can't pass connections or queues across threads unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

After multiple attempts I finally figured out a way that would work. As connections can't be passed across threads, the `socket.accept` needs to be done from within the client thread. To avoid spawning more than one, the loop is paused until the thread sends back word that it has a connection.

In order to send the same queue item to each of them, another thread is run that has access to all the queues, so it can take one item and duplicate it. As the list of queues changes all the time, it must be recreated after each connection.

Instead of copying over 100 lines of code, here is the general idea in pseudocode:

```
sock = socket.connect()

threads = []
queues = []
while True:

    #Start a client thread ready for connection
    #Make sure to empty the queue before receiving messages
    queues.append(Queue())
    threads.append(Thread(client_thread, (sock, queues[-1], main_queue)))
    threads[-1].start()

    #Start the middleman thread
    #It receives an input from one queue and sends it a list of other queues
    #Restart required when the number of threads changes
    middleman.quit()
    middleman = Thread(middleman_thread, (main_queue, queues))
    middleman.start()

    #Wait for connection to be made
    addr = queue.get()
    print '{}:{} connected.'.format(*addr)

    #Close any threads with disconnected clients
    for thread in threads:
        if not thread.isAlive():
             del thread
             del queue
```